# Checking multiple rvest set_values boxes with an apply or map function

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply, rvest

This question refers to the answer from [R scraping with a dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532773/r-scraping-with-a-dropdown-menu).

This works perfect, but in the interested of tidying code, I'm trying to lapply all the desired categories, and I can't get it to work. I tried the following (and many others), but no success:

```
cats <- paste0("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CB",toupper(c('fgp','fgm','ftm','ftp','3pm','pts','reb','ast','stl','to'))) 
form_function <- function(x) {pgform[[1]][[5]][[paste0(x)]]$value <- "checked"} 
lapply(cats, form_function)
```

It also works putting it all in the set_values function, but again, code is very repetitive:

```
filled_form <-set_values(pgform[[1]],
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDSHOW" = "400",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBFGM" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBFGP" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBFTM" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBFTP" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CB3PM" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBPTS" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBREB" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBAST" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBSTL" = "checked",
                         "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CBTO" = "checked")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a better application for a `for` loop instead of `lapply` function.

```
cats <- paste0("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CB",toupper(c('fgp','fgm','ftm','ftp','3pm','pts','reb','ast','stl','to'))) 

for (field in cats){
   pgform[[1]][[5]][[field]]$value <- "checked"
}
```